# Como usar o valor de uma variável para definir uma chave de um objeto?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Queria retornar um JSON do MongoDB com alguns filtros, o problema é, quando eu tento passar uma variável pela função, não funciona, esse é o código:

```js
async find(req, res) {
    const { filter, input } = req.body;
    console.log(filter);
    console.log(input);
    const clients = await Client.find({ filter : { '$regex' : input, '$options' : 'i' } });
    console.log(clients);
    return res.json(clients);
},
```

Os consoles logs ficam:

```
name
testinput
[]
```

Se eu trocar:

```js
const clients = await Client.find({ filter : { '$regex' : input, '$options' : 'i' } });
```

por:

```js
const clients = await Client.find({ 'name' : { '$regex' : input, '$options' : 'i' } });
```

Funciona, mas por que não consigo passar uma váriavel? Preciso pesquisar com vários diferentes filtros

Comment: É lib nativa ou mongoose? Faça o seguinte teste para ver o que ocorre, defina dessa forma a busca `const filter = {name: {'$regex' : input, '$options' : 'i' }}`  e `Client.find(filter) ` também teste dessa forma `const filter2= {'$regex' : input, '$options' : 'i' }` e `Client.find({name: filter2})`. Retorne com feedback.

Comment: OBRIGADO por tentar me ajudar

Usando no front:
const response = await api.post(`/client/find`, { "filter": this.state.filterSelected, "input": this.state.textFind });

No back:
https://hastebin.com/yoyoruxaki.coffeescript

Retornou isso:
https://hastebin.com/futixeletu.rb

Comment: Então mas deu erro `Identifier 'filter' has already been declared` você declarou duas vezes filter, renomeie ela para algo como filter3 e coloque await na frent do client.find em ambas as tentativas.

Comment: Assim? https://hastebin.com/tasatasife.coffeescript
Printou isso:
(node:5429) DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead.
{ name: { '$regex': '', '$options': 'i' } }
{ '$regex': '', '$options': 'i' }


Mas aí onde entra o filtro?
Se eu faço 'name' como filtro, funciona,se eu coloco uma variavel, não funciona, não faz sentido, mesmo passando 'name' por parametro da variavel como eu mostrei em cima

Isso funciona:
const clients = await Client.find({ 'name' : { '$regex' : input, '$options' : 'i' } });

Comment: Sim, o client nao entende isso aqui `await Client.find({ filter : { '$regex' : input, '$options' : 'i' } });`  porque você esta falando assim, ei busque para eu todos os `filter` com a seguinte regra, mas o filter não é um campo do banco e sim uma variável com valores desconhecidos para o find, já o `nome ` é um campo do banco que vai ser buscando com uma regra especifica. Bom você deve estar usando mongoose então de um olhada [aqui](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

Comment: Eu queria que você testasse o que eu te passei para ver se inserindo a variável filter com o campo de busca e a regra, para ver se ia retornar os possíveis resultados, nesse exemplo `filter = {name: {'$regex' : input, '$options' : 'i' }}` esta passando para o find o campo de busca e a regra de busca e inserindo o filter direto no find `await Client.find(filter)`, seria como se o filter tivesse vindo via body para inserção direta no find, eu faço algo parecido em meus projetos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No próprio JavaScript, um objeto pode ser criado de duas formas:

```js
// Forma 1
let obj1 = { name: "Fulano", age: 37 };

// Forma 2
let obj2 = { "name": "Fulano", "age": 37 };
```

Ou seja, a chave pode ser definida com aspas, ou sem aspas.

Tendo em vista isto, quando você passa como argumento o objeto:

```js
{ filter : { '$regex' : input, '$options' : 'i' } }
```

Você está passando um objeto que tem a chave `filter`, pois, essa forma de *definição de chave* é aceita. No entanto, como o `input` está sendo passado como um valor, e não como uma chave, o JavaScript considera que você está usando uma variável.

Portanto, uma forma para que você possa usar o valor de uma variável como a chave de um objeto, seria usar `JSON.parse` para converter uma *string* em um objeto, desse jeito:

```js
let jsonObject = JSON.parse(`{ "${filter}" : { "$regex" : "${input}", "$options" : "i" } }`);

const clients = await Client.find(jsonObject);
```

Já outra forma (até mais simples) — e já essa com base nas definições do ES6 — seria usar a definição de uma chave através do valor retornado por uma expressão, dessa forma:

```js
const clients = await Client.find({
    [filter]: {
        "$regex": input,
        "$options": "i"
    }
});
```

Ou seja, ali em `[filter]`, será definida uma chave com o valor da variável `filter`.

E quando diz-se *"expressão"*, pode-se pensar até mesmo em expressões de concatenação de *strings*, por exemplo:

```js
{
    [filter]: {
        ['$' + 'regex']: input,
        "$options": "i"
    }
}
```

Ou seja, a chave resultante de `['$' + 'regex']` será `"$regex"`.

Essa forma pode se tornar mais interessante, pois acaba deixando o código, de certa forma, mais "limpo", além de não exigir que utilize-se de uma funcionalidade adicional que agora se demonstra "desnecessária".

Porém, note-se que para usar essa funcionalidade no lado do *front-end*, pode se tornar necessário a implementação de algumas ferramentas, como o [*Babel*](https://babeljs.io/), para que haja compatibilidade com navegadores mais antigos (isto é, a navegadores que não "suportam" o ES6).

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: entendi, mas não tenho certeza que seja isso, porque não funcionou, deu erros aqui:

https://hastebin.com/ilulupodob.cs

Comment: Ao invés das aspas simples (`'`), use as aspas duplas (`"`). Eu havia me esquecido que o `JSON.parse` só converte as strings que possuem chaves definidas com aspas duplas. Desculpa aí...

Comment: Eu editei a resposta, colocando a forma correta...

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

```
    const { field, value } = 
    req.body

    const updateItem = {

        [field]: value

    }
```

Isso me foi útil para atualizar um campo específico no mongoDB. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).